# How can I average all bands in a single PostGIS raster table?

Tags: postgresql, average, postgis, mean, raster

I have 1 year of daily climate data in a single raster table in a postgis-enabled postgres database. It has 365 bands (one for each day). How do I average all the bands to get a single annual average per pixel? I tried [ST_Union](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Union.html), but it returns all the bands, or I'm not using it correctly:

```
select rid, st_union(rast, 'MEAN')
from climate_table
group by rid;
```

I figured out a workaround using ST_DumpAsPolygons, but it is very slow. Any suggestions appreciated. (Also, I can't believe "bands" is not yet a tag, and I don't have enough reputation to create it!)

Comment: ST_Union should work if you have one raster per day with 1 band each. (One db row per day). You can probably use generate_series(1,365) for the band index and join on that with ST_Band(original_raster,index) then use the resulting set of rasters with ST_Union(rast,'MEAN')

Comment: @clamp, I have a large raster (~500,000 cells) and each band is a separate day. If I had "one raster per day with 1 band each (One db row per day)", I wouldn't have this problem. Also, "one raster per day with 1 band each" and "One db row per day" sound like 2 very different things

Comment: Is that raster file accessible to the public?

Comment: ST_Union takes a set of raster - not a set of bands, I mentioned the functions you could use to transform your raster in a query. You want a with- clause or a subselect that yields 365 rows with one raster per row (i.e. per day). This can be aggregated by ST_Union

Comment: Rasters are available as NetCDFs from here: ftp://gdo-dcp.ucllnl.org/pub/dcp/archive/cmip5/loca/LOCA_2016-04-02/CanESM2/16th/rcp85/r1i1p1/tasmin/
I actually need to process about 1,000 of them, hence my search for a faster method. Thanks for looking into this. I'll give your test case a try, but I'm beginning to think it won't be any faster than using ST_DumpAsPolygons or ST_PixelsAsPoints. I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Union.html) he function `ST_Union()` takes a set of rasters. You have a raster with many bands.
You can use `ST_Union` but you have to transform your data into a set of rasters where each one contains 1 band first.

Here is a testcase:

```
-- Create a table and add a row with an empty raster:

CREATE TABLE r_src(rid integer primary key, rast raster);
INSERT INTO r_src values(1,ST_MakeEmptyRaster(4,4,0,0,1));

-- Add two band layers to this raster one with value 10 for each point,
-- the other with value 4 for each point.

UPDATE r_src
    SET rast = ST_AddBand(rast,'4BUI'::text,10)
WHERE rid = 1;
UPDATE r_src
    SET rast = ST_AddBand(rast,'4BUI'::text,4)
WHERE rid = 1;

-- check what we have

SELECT  (rmd).width, (rmd).height, (rmd).numbands
FROM (SELECT ST_MetaData(rast) As rmd
    FROM r_src WHERE rid = 1) AS foo;
-- 4| 4| 2  --ok

-- output rasterdata in hex for both bands:

SELECT ST_AsHexWKB(rast) As rastbin FROM r_src WHERE rid=1;


-- output rasterdata for the 2nd band (note the '...040404' point values 
-- compared to '...0A0A0A' if you select the band at idx 1

SELECT ST_AsHexWKB(ST_Band(rast,2))FROM r_src WHERE rid = 1;


-- now step by step...
-- src is the single rast in our source table,
-- in extracted this is joined with a generated series
-- for each value in the series a new raster is returned 
-- containing the band at that index:

WITH src       AS (SELECT rast FROM r_src WHERE rid = 1),
     extracted AS (SELECT ST_Band(src.rast,ser.idx) 
                   FROM src
                   JOIN generate_series(1,2) AS ser(idx ) ON true)
SELECT * FROM extracted;

-- outputs 2 rows with one raster each, and each raster containing one band

-- now aggreagating these:

WITH src       AS (SELECT rast FROM r_src WHERE rid = 1),
     extracted AS (SELECT ST_Band(src.rast,ser.idx) AS r_day
                   FROM src
                   JOIN generate_series(1,2) AS ser(idx ) ON true)
SELECT ST_Union(r_day,1,'MEAN') FROM extracted;

-- outputs one row with the resulting raster holding one band 
-- that band contains the 'MEAN' point values '...070707'
```

I checked this out with a dataset you [linked](ftp://gdo-dcp.ucllnl.org/pub/dcp/archive/cmip5/loca/LOCA_2016-04-02/CanESM2/16th/rcp85/r1i1p1/tasmin/tasmin_day_CanESM2_rcp85_r1i1p1_21000101-21001231.LOCA_2016-04-02.16th.nc) to and imported it into postgres using `raster2pgsql`. Due to its size, I decided to split it into tiles of 100x100 and got a table with 45 rows. Now to convert the whole raster I used the following statement:

```
CREATE TABLE averages AS
WITH extracted AS (SELECT src.rid , ST_Band(src.rast,ser.idx) AS r_day
                   FROM rastertest src
                   JOIN generate_series(1,365) AS ser(idx ) ON true)
SELECT rid, ST_Union(r_day,1,'MEAN') AS rast
FROM extracted
GROUP BY rid;
```

This creates a new table averages with the average values only.

Comment: Many thanks @clamp for seeing this through. Sorry for my confusion previously. You explained this well, and your example was perfect. One other possible method I discovered for my particular issue is to use gdal_calc.py on the netcdf files before loading to db. I also discovered that these rasters can be loaded very quickly using large tiles (i.e. 480x245, or only 4 rows) and the ST_Union function takes the same amount of time - useful when loading/processing hundreds of these.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. The Statement to create the averages took 3 minutes to complete here (For the whole raster). I also thought it might be faster to do it before import...